# ¿Como puedo ejecutar este algoritmo en java?

Tags: java

Hola a todos espero que esten muy bien,
quisiera saber porfavor como puedo implementar este codigo para ejecutarlo en el main de java:

```
public class InterpolationSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        System.out.println("Introduzca los numeros separados por coma");
        String[] numeros=br.readLine().split(",");
        int[] array = new int[numeros.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            array[i] = Integer.parseInt( numeros[i] );
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(numeros[i]+" ");
    }

    }

    static int InterpolationSearch(int []A, int x) {
        int lower_bound=0;
        int upper_bound=A.length-1;
        int index=-1;
        /* if upper bound is less than lower bound, there is not a feasible solution */
        while(lower_bound<upper_bound)
        {
            int middlepoint=lower_bound+(upper_bound-lower_bound)/(A[upper_bound] - A[lower_bound]) * (x - A[lower_bound]);
            if (x== A[middlepoint]) {
                /* x has been found */
                index=middlepoint;
                break;
            }else{
                if(x<A[middlepoint]) {
                    upper_bound=middlepoint-1;
                }else {
                    lower_bound=middlepoint+1;
                }
            }

        }

        if (lower_bound==upper_bound && A[lower_bound]==x)
        {
            index=lower_bound;
        }
        return index;

    }

    }
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que el usuario pueda ingresar los numeros separados por coma, y luego introduzca el valor que desea buscar.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: No entiendo la dificultad. Me parece que lo que ya tienes es mucho mas complicado que lo que te falta por hacer (a menos que este código no lo escribistes tu). ¿Qué ***específicamente*** es lo que no logras hacer?

Comment: Se me ha pedido poner en java el algoritmo InterpolationSearch mediante un pseudocodigo (el cual ya esta implementado), mi dificultad es que nunca habia usado un codigo con recursividad y no se como hacer funcionar este algortimo, gracias por responder.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera para obtener los datos

```
String texto = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(new JFrame(), "Ingrese los valores?");
    System.out.println("Resp: "+texto);
```